# Find date of newest release in github

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to write a script that will get the most recent release for a specific repository in github, and then display the commits since that release was created.

I know I can get the commits using this:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

And I would like to get the `published_at` date of the most recent release so I can use it to create a request to the github API like this:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/RepoOwner/MyRepo/commits?since=2015-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Where `2015-01-01T00:00:00Z` happens to be the `published_at` date of the most recent release. I know I can get a list of releases like this:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository

My plan was to get the list of releases in descending order by date, and then just examine the first one to figure out what the date of the release was. But sorting doesn't seem to work. Specifying that the results should be sorted by `sort=published_at` with either `asc` or `desc` for `order` seem to have the same results (`https://api.github.com/repos/ReporOwner/myrepo/releases?sort=published_at&order=desc` vs. `https://api.github.com/repos/ReporOwner/myrepo/releases?sort=published_at&order=asc`). I'm guessing github API doesn't support sorting on this result set list.

Is there some other way I can get the date of most recent release?